# Why php json response does not send back the data array to ajax jquery request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have made an ajax request to the php server where I send a data from a form request and I would to get back the same data from the server just for testing requests and responses of the same data throwing between the client and the server.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "addRaces",
    dataType: "json",
    data : sending_data,
    success : ...
})
```

`sending_data` is an array like `{field_form_name : value}`

The server responds to the request with the following code :

```
$data = [];
foreach ($request->Input() as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = $value;
}

return json_encode($data);
```

The same data should come back to the client, but nothing happen with an `alert(response)` or a jquery showing debug data like  `$('#debug').html(response);`

The strange thing coming up when I try to push the server answer like

```
return json_encode([
  'debug' => $data['name']
]);
```

and showing results to client like

$('#debug').html(response.debug);

it is working for a single key-value response showing the properly value field I have send from the client.
Other wise whether I send the full `data` as an array nothing is shown in the debug area of the client.

Comment: any errors in your developer tools console? what is shown in the developer tools network for this request?

Comment: you should use `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: I have used `JSON.stringify()` to pull out data as a string received from the server showing all I needed. I tryied with an `echo` istruction from the server, but the result does not change. The developer tool in network tab does not show any errors. I think I can use the JSON function in javascript to show the answer from the server.

Answer (score 0):

`return json_encode($data);` wont work. as it is returning the json string to the calling method which is not your jQuery at front end. Don't confuse front end (html javascript, jQuery, etc...) with back end (PHP) the two of them are running in different machines. One at client end and another at your server.

you should use `echo json_encode($data);` this will output the json string and your web server will send it to the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are echoing the data not returning as @bansi said, if you are echoing it already then debug using `var_dump(json_encode($data))` . If `json_encode()` found errors it will return `False` instead of the expected json array.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug using the developer tools instead of using code `$('#debug').html(response.debug);`. The Network tab of developer tools is very useful to debug HTTP requests, it will show response header and body of your requests.

In your case, just change `return` to `echo` like [@bansi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393030/3872002). The `return` command does not print the data so you did not get anything in the response.